# Raspberry PI, raw reading a register value in C

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Can someone please show me some example on how to read values from Raspberry Pi registers?
I need to check byte in  AUX_MU_LSR_REG (0x7E21 5054) but i don't know how to do this without usage of any additional libraries. 
I tried to: 
(here i modify the oryginal post)

****************************************Start of the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>



#define BCM2708     0x20000000
#define UART_BASE   (BCM2708+0x215000)
#define PAGE_SIZE   (4*1024)
#define BLOCK_SIZE  (4*1024)



int mem_fd;                 
void *uart_map;                 
volatile unsigned *uart;            




int main()
{

printf("start\n");

if((mem_fd=open("/dev/mem",O_RDWR|O_SYNC))<0)
{
printf("can't open /dev/mem \n");
exit(-1);
}
else printf("stream_file open OK \n");

if((uart_map=malloc(BLOCK_SIZE))==0)
printf("malloc fail\n");
else printf("GPIO_mallocation OK %d \n", (int)uart_map );


uart_map=mmap   (NULL,          //any address in our space
BLOCK_SIZE,         //map length
PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,   //Enable reading and writing to maped memmory
MAP_SHARED,     //Shares with other processes
mem_fd,         //File to map
UART_BASE       //Offset toUART peripheral
);

if(uart_map==MAP_FAILED)
{
printf("mmap error %d", (int)uart_map);
exit(-1);
}
else printf("GPIO mapping OK \n");
uart=(volatile unsigned* )uart_map;
int i;

for(i=0;i<32;i++)
{
printf("adress:%x ",uart+i);
printf("value:%x\n",*(uart+i));
}





printf("stop\n");
return 0;
}
```

`
*******************************************end of code
Now i don't really remember how i display the 0 but in the above code i get pointer conflict.

What is the uart pointing to? In theory it should display the values but after few weeks i can't make it running.

Hope you can help me somehow

Comment: The technique you are using is the correct way to do this. Can you post an actual snippet of your code? That would be easier to read than what you posted.

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully compiled the example [here](http://elinux.org/Rpi_Datasheet_751_GPIO_Registers) and been able to read and write digital values from GPIO pins with a little modification to that code.

You're essentially heading in the right direction: `mmap()` a range specified in the datasheet for your particular GPIO, SPI or whichever register you need, and then read and write from that address.  That's the basis of all the GPIO programming on the RPi.

There are some special bitfields that you should pay attention to, but as I mentioned, these are all in the datasheets for the Pi at elinux.org

**note**: to `mmap()` the system registers you need to be running as the superuser.

Comment: Idrumm. I have in my aplication code which accesses the GPIO exact the way as you describe and it works perfectly. I tried to use the same code and only changed the address of the memory area from the GPIO_Base to the UART_Base. The problem is that it seems not returning real memory values as everything is 0.

Comment: @Gregorek: If you post your code, I can try it out on my PI, and see if there's anything else I can do  help.  Without code though, I'm stumped.

Comment: Idrumm i added the code in the oryginall post. Can't make it running now due to pointers conflict.